# ld: warning : directory not found for option '-L./...'

Tags: macos, mpi, mpich

I'm trying to get mpich 3.0.4 installed right on my system (Mac OS X 10.10.2) from the shell (which I use with tcsh). So I tar-ed it, then configured (./configure --prefix=$DIR/mpich) it, and then entered make.

All seemed to go well, but at the end, I've got those two warnings appearing :

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L./src/mpl'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L./src/openpa/src'
```

and when I test it later (with a test from the tutorial, so the error does not come from here), it prints the following :

```
ld: targeted OS version does not support use of thread local variables in _MPIU_Thread_CS_enter_lockname_recursive_impl_ for architecture x86_64
```

I would be very grateful for any kind of advice (having in mind that I am rather a beginner).
Thank you !

edit : for information, I'm using this tutorial : http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/OnLineTutorial/compilation_tutorial.php#STEP2

Comment: If I want to re-do the installation, should I delete the different files produced ? The file produced by the make install command and the file issued from the archive ? If so, is there any precaution to take ?

Answer (score 0):

This immensely frustrating bug hit several platforms, including MVAPICH.  Fortunately, it  has been fixed -- though I can't tell you exactly how:

- http://trac.mpich.org/projects/mpich/ticket/1840
- http://mailman.cse.ohio-state.edu/pipermail/mvapich-discuss/2013-April/004359.html

If you try 3.1.4 this problem should go away.